# Display '⤭' in iOS safari through CSS content property

Tags: ios, css

The html looks like this:

```
<html>

<head>
    <style type="text/css">

    h1:before
    {
      content: '\292d';
    }

    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <h1>Sample Text</h1>
</body>

</html>
```

So, I've already converted the `'⤭'` character to ASCII which shows fine in my desktop's browser; however, on iPhone, it's blank!

Comment: did you try from media query

Comment: ... why would you need a media query for that?

Comment: What version of iOS are you testing on?

Comment: I don't think it's supported at all so there's nothing for you to do except use a small image of it.

Comment: @BoltClock I've tried it on iOS 8 and iOS 9. Any other suggestions except using an image? (using just code)

Comment: Try setting a proper web-font which contains the character.

Answer (score 0):

The problem could be with `content: '\292d';` even though they say `content` is supported with safari 1.0 and up it still does not work properly.
i used it for displaying images and it used to show up in inspect element but not in browser window, the entity `'\292d'` is infact supported

instead Try putting it directly inside the tag, or use javascipt if you want it to be dynamically inserted